# ORA-01033 "ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress" caused by ORA-10567 "REDO is inconsistent with data block"

Tags: oracle, restore

I faced an error while logging to database with regular user (non SYS/DBA):

```
C:\Users\user>sqlplus tester@orcl
ORA-01033 ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
```

However I can connect via `sysman@orcl as sysdba` user. Before I start with solving the issue, below are the errors that can tell what state my orcl database is in:

```
SQL> select * from dba_data_files;
ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only
```

So I use `recover database` and `alter database open` commands and they point at the same logfile and block:

```
SQL> recover database;
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [3020], [3], [192], [12583104], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-10567: Redo is inconsistent with data block (file# 3, block# 192, file offset is 1572864 bytes)
ORA-10564: tablespace UNDOTBS1
ORA-01110: data file 3: 'E:\ORACLE\ORADATA\ORCL\UNDOTBS01.DBF'
ORA-10560: block type 'KTU SMU HEADER BLOCK'

SQL> alter database open;
ORA-01172: recovery of thread 1 stuck at block 192 of file 3
ORA-01151: use media recovery to recover block, restore backup if needed
```

I did also that:

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
ORA-01109: database not open

Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.

SQL> startup mount;
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service
SQL> startup mount;
ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
ORA-01041: internal error. hostdef extension doesn't exist
```

After restarting oracle.exe service and diagnosing the database, the "redo" error has a bit changed (block 705):

```
ORA-10567: Redo is inconsistent with data block (file# 3, block# 705, file offset is 5775360 bytes)
```

My log files:

```
SQL> select * from v$logfile;

    GROUP# STATUS  TYPE    MEMBER                                IS_
---------- ------- ------- ------------------------------------- ---
         3         ONLINE  E:\ORACLE\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO03.LOG     NO
         2         ONLINE  E:\ORACLE\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO02.LOG     NO
         1         ONLINE  E:\ORACLE\ORADATA\ORCL\REDO01.LOG     NO
```

I'm in a point where I cannot use my database at full even by a sysman user. Please help, advise.

EDIT:
After following this [guide](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Database_Administration/DBA_34.shtml) which ideally addresses my situation, I get different error and cannot follow it anymore:

```
SQL> alter system switch logfile;
ORA-01109: database not open

SQL> startup
ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first
```

Question aside: Who can tell if this db is open or not? :-)

Comment: The `STATUS` column of the [`v$instance`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2002.htm#REFRN30105) view will tell you your database state. [`ORA-0600`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600) sounds like a nasty problem and often calls for support. I would try to read alert log and perform complete recovery first, then ask for Oracle support.

Answer (score -1):

Since the problem is in your undo tablespace. You can drop it and create a new one. Steps in this article:

http://www.my-whiteboard.com/how-to-drop-and-recreate-oracle-undo-tablespace-and-its-data-files/

Comment: after shutdown immediate I fail to STARTUP RESTRICT MOUNT pfile=... due to ORA-12514 "TNS does not know service..." I stop and start the Windows service for ORCL db. I log in again, but do not shutdown. I try to drop undo tbs, but receive ORA-01109 "db is not open". Still need help.

Comment: I tried to follow this [link](http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested.htm) on ORA-12514 and in return I received  `SQL> STARTUP RESTRICT MOUNT pfile=E:\Oracle\pfileUNDO.ora`  
`ORA-01506: missing or illegal database name` (notifying @ibre5041)

Comment: -1 because this is nonsense. The undo tablespace holds information necessary to undo the open transactions after the archives/redos are applied.To change the undo tablespace the database must be open and the tablespace must not be damaged.

Answer (score -1):

@user129400 is right - replacing UNDO tbs is a good idea. You can also try:

- contact Oracle support
- disable parallel media recovery
- If you have at least two copies of redo logs you can also check whether they are identical. If not remove one of the copies
- bypass media recovery completely, start the database, export application schemas and import them into newly created database

PS: you database is not open, but probably is still mounted(the previous state before open)

Comment: `RECOVER DATABASE NOPARALLEL` does not help. It results with the same error:  `ORA-10567: REDO inconsistent`  `ORA-10564: tablespace UNDO`

Comment: -1 except "contact Oracle support" all this advice is nonsense